# Popover requirements for iPad compatibility on iPhone targeted app

Tags: ios

I have an app that allows the user to choose a photo from a library. I know that iPad requires you to use a popover for this. I want my app target to be iPhone only and not universal, so when I run the app on 'iPad' in simulator the popover does not appear when choosing from library (it goes to a new screen just like on iPhone). Is this allowed since it's iPhone target, or do I have to make it universal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's an iPhone-only app. It should do what iPhone apps do, even run when run on an iPad in "iPhone emulator" mode.

You are fine having the photo library picker appear full screen, even when the iPhone app is run on an iPad.